# Speed up self joined sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a relatively simply query I am trying to run on a table:

```
select distinct(a.question_id || a.app_name) 
from quick_stats a
join quick_stats b on a.question_id = b.question_id 
                  and a.app_name != b.app_name;
```

Unfortunately, the query is taking a very long time to run.

I believe this is because there are about 4 million records in the table and since it must check each record against every other record in the table this means there are 16 trillion checks.

How can I write this query so it doesnt make so many checks?

Comment: have you add index to the table

Comment: In my opinion, if you are already using an index and there is no way that you can add a `where`, there is not much more you can do.

Comment: I forgot to ask: which storage engine do you use? This also has an effect on how fast your select query is

Comment: It uses MyISAM.  I tried to change it to InnoDB but when I did, using SQL WorkBench 6.0 and MySQL version 5.6.12, Workbench crashed and the changes were not made.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly a table design issue.
Check if question_id and app_name are indexed

Keep in mind: the less indexed columns you have, the better your performance is
An index is stored in an extra hash table that points to the full entry in your database

That said: if you have indexed question_id and app_name your query searches in some kind of a seperate table and does not have to read the full table with all their columns

A very useful source about how to index a table correctly is: http://use-the-index-luke.com/welcome

Comment: thanks, I have tried to implement this, but I'm not entirely sure if I understood the suggestion correctly.  I also added a new column called qid_and_app_name which is equal to id || app_name to save a bit of extra time, and I created indexes for the qid_and_app_name and question_id columns.  I then updated the query to the following:
`select distinct(a.qid_and_app_name) from quick_stats a
join quick_stats b on a.qid_and_app_name = b.qid_and_app_name and a.question_id != b.question_id;`
However it is still running after about 10 minutes.  Did I do anything incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please add the result of "SHOW INDEX FROM quick_stats" to the question?